# knockout trigger ovservable refresh from a function in the view model

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to force reload knockout after a event so that the data is refreshed. My view code looks as follows.

```
var targeturl = "/ajax{{ event_id }}/";
var blockurl = "/ajax/block/{{ event_id }}/";
var page = "0";

$(function () {
    $.getJSON(targeturl + page, function (data) {
        var midPoint = Math.floor((data.length) / 2);
        var data1 = data.slice(0, midPoint);
        var data2 = data.slice(midPoint);

        // add block, feature and download ids
        data1.forEach(function (item) {
            item.block_id = "block-" + item._id;
            item.feature_id = "feature-" + item._id;
            item.download_id = "download-" + item._id;
        });

        data2.forEach(function (item) {
            item.block_id = "block-" + item._id;
            item.feature_id = "feature-" + item._id;
            item.download_id = "download-" + item._id;
        });

        var viewModel = {
            socialData1: ko.observableArray(data1),
            socialData2: ko.observableArray(data2),
            blockItem: function(item) {
                var tempid = item.block_id.split("-")[1];
                $.getJSON(blockurl + tempid, function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    socialData1.valueHasMutated();
                    socialData2.valueHasMutated();
                })
                .error(function () {
                    alert('error');
                });
            }
        };
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    })
    .error(function () {
        alert('error');
    });
});
```

How do I force knockout reload in `blockItem` function inside the `viewModel`.

I want to re run the `$.getJSON` function to get the updated data.

Comment: Your viewmodel should be defined outside the `getJSON` function. Within the `getJSON` function, populate its members.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define `viewModel` variable outside your first `getJSON`. Thus you would be able to call `viewModel.blockItem(yourItem)` at any time.

I would create it something like this:

```
var targeturl = "/ajax{{ event_id }}/";
var blockurl = "/ajax/block/{{ event_id }}/";
var page = "0";

var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.socialData1 = ko.observableArray();
  self.socialData2 = ko.observableArray();
  self.blockItem = function(item) {
    var tempid = item.block_id.split("-")[1];
    $.getJSON(blockurl + tempid, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        self.socialData1.valueHasMutated();
        self.socialData2.valueHasMutated();
      })
      .error(function() {
        alert('error');
      });
  }

  self.init = function() {
    $.getJSON(targeturl + page, function(data) {
        var midPoint = Math.floor((data.length) / 2);
        var data1 = data.slice(0, midPoint);
        var data2 = data.slice(midPoint);

        // add block, feature and download ids
        data1.forEach(function(item) {
          item.block_id = "block-" + item._id;
          item.feature_id = "feature-" + item._id;
          item.download_id = "download-" + item._id;
        });

        data2.forEach(function(item) {
          item.block_id = "block-" + item._id;
          item.feature_id = "feature-" + item._id;
          item.download_id = "download-" + item._id;
        });

        self.socialData1(data1);
        self.socialData2(data2),
        self.blockItem(item); //call blockItem if need here; not sure what you have to pass as item there
      })
      .error(function() {
        alert('error');
      });
  };

  self.init(); //run getjson first time
};

var myModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(myModel);
```

If you need you later can call `myModel.blockItem(item)` if you need.

Answer (score 0):

You are rebuilding the viewModel when you just want to change the data. Declare your viewModel outside the data-getting functions.

```
var viewModel = {
  socialData1: ko.observableArray(),
  socialData2: ko.observableArray(),
  blockItem: function(item) {
    var tempid = item.block_id.split("-")[1];
    $.getJSON(blockurl + tempid, populateViewModel)
    .error(function() {
      alert('error');
    });
  }
};
```

You see I made `populateViewModel` the action for the `getJSON`. It looks like both your initial `getJSON` and your `blockItem` should populate the viewModel in the same way, so both can use that function (you could make this a method in the viewModel if you prefer):

```
function populateViewModel(data) {
  var midPoint = Math.floor((data.length) / 2);
  var data1 = data.slice(0, midPoint);
  var data2 = data.slice(midPoint);

  // add block, feature and download ids
  data1.forEach(function(item) {
    item.block_id = "block-" + item._id;
    item.feature_id = "feature-" + item._id;
    item.download_id = "download-" + item._id;
  });

  data2.forEach(function(item) {
    item.block_id = "block-" + item._id;
    item.feature_id = "feature-" + item._id;
    item.download_id = "download-" + item._id;
  });

  viewModel.socialData1(data1);
  viewModel.socialData2(data2);
}
```

To start up the program, you just apply the bindings and populate the viewModel.

```
$(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
  $.getJSON(targeturl + page, populateViewModel)
    .error(function() {
      alert('error');
    });
});
```